# Finding string contained in CSV file and computing a sum

Tags: python, pandas, csv

It's my first time working with Panda, so I am trying to wrap my head around all of its functionalities.

Essentially, I want to download my bank statements in CSV and search for a keyword (e.g. steam) and compute the money I spent.

I was able to use panda to locate lines that contain my keyword, but I do not know how to iterate through them and attribute the cost of that purchase to a variable that I will sum up as the iteration grows.

If you look in the image I upload, I am able to find the lines containing my keyword in the dataframe, but what I want to do is for each line found, I want to take the content of the col[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NUUl.png) and sum it up together.

[Attempt At Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG7qH.png)

```
# importing pandas module
import pandas as pd

keyword = input("Enter the keyword you wish to search in the statement: ")


# reading csv file from url
df = pd.read_csv('accountactivity.csv',header=None)

dff=df.loc[df[1].str.contains(keyword,case=False)]

value=df.values[68][2] #Fetches value of a specific cell in the CSV/dataframe created

print(dff)

print(value)
```

**EDIT:**
I essentially was almost able to complete the code I wanted, using only the CSV reader, but I can't get that code to find substrings. It only works if I enter the exact same string, meaning if I enter **netflix** it doesn't work, I would need to write it exactly as it appears on the statement like **NETFLIX.COM       _V**. Here is another screenshot of that working code. I essentially want to mimic that with the capabilities of just finding substrings.

[Working Code using CSV reader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NUUl.png)

```
import csv

data=[]

with open("accountactivity.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)


keyword = input("Enter the keyword you wish to search in the statement: ")

col = [x[1] for x in data]

Sum = 0

if keyword in col:
    for x in range(0, len(data)):
        if keyword == data[x][1]:
            PartialSum=float(data[x][2])
            Sum=Sum+PartialSum
            print(data[x][1])

    print("The sum for expenses at ",keyword," is of: ",Sum,"$",sep = '')

else:
    print("Keyword returned no results.")
```

The format of the CSV is the following: [CSV Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj3po.png)

**column 0** Date of transaction

**column 1** Name of transaction

**column 2** Money spent from account

**column 3** Money received to account

The CSV file downloaded directly from my bank has no headers. So I refer to columns using col[0] etc...

Thanks for your help, I will continue meanwhile to look at how to potentially do this.

Comment: you could melt the numerical lines then just apply a `.sum` but i think its important you go back a step and see what schema is provided for the bank data (i.e columns nad datatypes), you can normally find this on your bank providers website.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You have given the relevant informations... but only in non copyable images :-( . They are enough to understand what you tried, but not to reproduce. And we insist on having a [mre] so that potential answerers can reproduce and test their solutions. If you give (in the question itself, search for *edit*...) enough input lines (even with dummy values) of the csv file and your current code **as text**, we could easily propose a fix, and test it before posting an answer. It costs you some more work, but in the end you can expect good answers...

Comment: ... And as far as I am concerned, I know that typos are a plague, so I really *hate* posting untested code in an answer.

Comment: @Umar.H: OP said it was a csv file. As csv is a textual format, it contains no information on the datatypes. They are infered by pandas `read_csv`, or on the other hand the `csv` module from the standard library only gives rows of string values.

Comment: @SergeBallesta that I understand, but from the picture there are no column names, normally there is an acompying CSV that offers the column names and datatypes, atleast that's the practice in the UK.

Comment: Sorry about that guys, I modified the post to contain the two codes I did and I also added a sample of the CSV so you can understand its format. I would have uploaded the whole CSV but it contains personal banking information hahaha. Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dff[dff.columns[col_index]].sum()
```

where `col_index` is the index of the column you want to sum together.

Comment: The first problem is the data in the column of interest is a string, so I have to have it in float so I can sum it up (When I used CSV reader). My other problem is how do I get it to sum the elements of the column of interest only for the indexes where my keyword was found?

Comment: I tried the line you gave me since I started to grasp how the dataframe works and it is exactly what I needed. I am trying to upvote your answer, but it is not letting me since I do not have the reputation, but it's the exact answer to my problem, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help. I ended up understanding more how dataframe with Pandas work and I used the command: *df[df.columns["col_index"]].sum()* (which was suggested to me by **Jonny Kong**) with the column of interest (which in my case is column 2 containing my expenses). It computes the sum of my expenses for the searched keyword which is what I need!

```
#Importing pandas module
import pandas as pd

#Keyword searched through bank statement
keyword = input("Enter the keyword you wish to search in the statement: ")


#Reading the bank statement CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('accountactivity.csv',header=None)

#Creating dataframe from bank statement with lines that match search keyword
dff=df.loc[df[1].str.contains(keyword,case=False)]

#Sum the column which contains total money spent on the keyword searched
Sum=dff[dff.columns[2]].sum()

#Prints the created dataframe
print("\n",dff,"\n")

#Prints the sum of expenses for the keyword searched
print("The sum for expenses at ",keyword," is of: ",Sum,"$",sep = '')
```

[Working Code!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HehYL.png)

Again, thanks everyone for helping and supporting me through my first post on SO!